# Excel Match Function When Value Shows Up More Then Once In The Column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to Match in Excel value from one worksheet in a list to another column in another worksheet in order to find the first row it shows up and match the result to an Index-Match function. I get an error of #NA even though I entered the right ranges. I believe it is because the value I am trying to match shows up few times, But I need just the first row of those few times.

Any suggestions how can I resolve this?

> =INDEX(SAP!$A$1:$BR$15772,MATCH('center'!A2,SAP!$N$1:$N$15772,0),15)

Comment: First rule for INDEX/MATCH is range size shall be the same. Note `157724` (INDEX) and `15772` (MATCH) is sure to throw surprises at you. Which one is correct out of these two?

Comment: `=INDEX(SAP!$A:$BR, MATCH('center'!A2, SAP!$N:$N, 0), 15)`

Comment: @Jeeped it is not working

Comment: @shrivallabha.redij I checked it and it still wont work

Comment: @RafaelOsipov post your updated formula. If possible include snapshots of referred ranges.

Comment: @shrivallabha.redij I edited. If you have another formula instead it can be tested. I can give screenshots, my workplace wont aloow it

Comment: @RafaelOsipov in principle there's nothing wrong with the formula logic. Can you tell result of formula `=MATCH(center!A2, SAP!$N:$N, 0)` alone? Secondly, can you tell what value is in `center!A2` i.e. numeric, alpha-numeric etc.?

Comment: @shrivallabha.redij the match formula has #NA result. the value in A2 is numeric but is has general format.

Comment: @RafaelOsipov This means there's certain mismatch in the data. Visually it may not appear so. Get the cell address of cell from `SAP!$N:$N` where you know it should be matching. Then assuming you have cell N2 where result is matching put formula `='center'!A2=SAP!N2` and see what you get. Also use `=EXACT('center'!A2,SAP!N2)`. If you are getting `false` in any one of these then check the cell contents. Therein lies your issue!

Comment: @shrivallabha.redij i made the check with EXACT function and it returned me TRUE. I found the problem I think. All the cells in SAP worksheet in column N are "Numbres who stored like text. you have solution for that?

Comment: You could force a string evaluation in `MATCH()`, something like `MATCH(""&'center'!A2,`

Comment: @RafaelOsipov I have provided couple of approaches. See if it works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on our discussion, here's what you can do.

**Approach 1**
Change data type to string like Richard Tompsett has suggested which will be:

`=INDEX(SAP!$A$1:$BR$15772,MATCH('center'!A2&"",SAP!$N$1:$N$15772,0),15)`

Notice the "&" concatenation after `'center'!A2` which will coerce number to text format.

**Approach 2**

Following shall also work. It should work for both numeric as well as text types.

`=LOOKUP(2,SEARCH(" "'center'!A2&" "," "&SAP!$N$1:$N$15772&" ",1),SAP!$O$1:$O$15772)`